# is RactiveJS 0.5 backwards compatible?

Tags: ractivejs

I'm asking this because after the edge version has been updated to 0.5.3 it caused my application to have problems with the observers. Meaning that, I have a queue, I'm listening to it's changes on `current` attribute, (works perfectly on 0.4.x (released on 29th June), can't remember the exact build version but that's the date), and now after removing the item from the Queue it says `'current' attribute of undefined`. As it tries to check another item in queue that doesn't exist.. I'll try to make a `ssce` tomorrow and update this.

Comment: We've tried to keep things as backwards-compatible as possible, but there have been many changes - see the [changelog](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md) for details. It sounds like one item in particular might be causing this - previously, observer callbacks were run inside a try-catch block, but that was making it hard to debug problems, so that's no longer the case. Because those callbacks run immediately, if you try to access `foo.current` before `foo` has a value, you would see an error that you wouldn't have before.

Comment: Mostly my fault :P It was hard to debug these things when Ractive was swallowing errors. And it's hard to report to error-logging libraries. Here's the issue: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking changes in 0.5.0 are listed [here on github](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/blob/dev/CHANGELOG.md)

One of those was that Ractive no longer ignores errors in observers or in the evaluation of expressions. More than likely it's in the init of observer where it doesn't matter for your use case, but now is causing an issue. Something like:

```
ractive.observe('foo', function(newValue, oldValue, keypath){
    if(oldValue.current) {

    }
})
```

Comment: `if (e && e.current) {...}` instead of `if (e.current) { ... }` solved my problem after reading the github issue regarding Joseph's comment on Ractive swallowing errors, as it was swallowing my `e` which could be undefined sometimes.